# Disable auto redirect_to in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can I disable auto redirect in ruby on rails, here my example: In my controllers

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @a = params[:link]
        if @a != nil
        Kernel.system("ls")
        redirect_to root_path
        else
        end
    end
   end
```

I don't want to redirect to root_path and stay in current pages, so I remove  `redirect_to root_path`, like this:

```
        def index
            @a = "abcd"
            if @a != nil
            Kernel.system("ls")
            else
            end
        end
```

But my app still auto redirect to root_path, I don't know how to fix that, please! help me:)

my routes:

```
 root 'welcome#index'
 match '/upload', to: 'welcome#index', via: 'post'
```

my html:

```
<%= form_tag(upload_path, :id => "form_check") do %>
        <%= text_field_tag :link %>
        <%= submit_tag("Process")%>
        <%end%>
```

Comment: So you want to stay on your upload page after submitting the form?

Comment: Yeah! correctly! Beacause If I redirect, all values in current pages will be remove

Comment: You know, I went back and looked at your code more closely, and what you're trying to do doesn't seem to make sense. You have a form that submits data that is never used and a controller that has a boolean test that always evaluates to 'true' @a = "abcd"; if @a != nil. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem isn't really auto redirect. You are "redirected" to your index because this line doesn't match: `match '/upload', to: 'welcome#index', via: 'post'`.

What you should do is to separate index and upload. It will be far easier to manage.

routes:

```
root 'welcome#index'
get 'form' => 'welcome#form', as: :form_path
post 'upload' => 'welcome#upload', as: :upload_path
```

form page:

```
<%= form_tag(upload_path, :id => "form_check") do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :link %>
  <%= submit_tag("Process")%>
<%end%>
```

And then you can create your new actions inside welcome, called form and upload. The last one redirect you to /form, so you can see your form again.

Comment: If you need more details just ask

Comment: Sorry! I tried it, but it doesn't work! so, I think I will try another way, may be sleep()